Capsule button not clickable in swift
Hi I am working on a study timer application. I have a reusable function that helps me set the hour minute and seconds however when i call it on the capsule that needs to be clicked. It will not click. Please if someone can guide me how to fix this. Thank you so much.
The function is at the bottom, func ContextMenuOptions.
@ViewBuilder
    func NewTimerView()->some View {
        VStack(spacing: 15) {
            Text("Add New Timer")
                .font(.title2.bold())
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
                .padding(.top, 10)
            
            HStack(spacing: 15) {
                Text("\(timerModel.hour) hr")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.3))
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                    .padding(.vertical, 12)
                    .background {
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.white.opacity(0.20))
                    }
                    .contextMenu{
                        ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: 12, hint: "hr") { value in
                            timerModel.hour = value
                        }
                    }
}

   @ViewBuilder
    func ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: Int, hint: String, onClick: @escaping (Int)->())-> some View {
        ForEach(0...maxValue,id: \.self) {value in
            Button("\(value) \(hint)") {
                onClick(value)
            }
        }
    }

I want the capsule to be clicked and a menu to pop up with 0-12hrs so that it can be set for up to 12 hours.

A ContextMenu is shown when a long press is made, not a tap. Your code works fine when a long press is performed. So are you asking, if there is another way to show the menu? A Picker with style .menu would be one way.

Hi I want it to be a tap not a long press what would i need to change for that?

As explained in a comment, a ContextMenu is shown when a long press is made, not a tap. Your code works fine when a long press is performed.
To make it work with a tap, instead of a long press, try using a Menu in place of the Text. The Text itself can become the label of the menu. Then the context menu is not needed, of course:
VStack(spacing: 15) {
    Text("Add New Timer")
        .font(.title2.bold())
        .foregroundStyle(.white)
        .padding(.top, 10)

    HStack(spacing: 15) {
        Menu {
            ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: 12, hint: "hr") { value in
                timerModel.hour = value
            }
        } label: {
            Text("\(timerModel.hour) hr")
                .font(.title3)
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
                .foregroundStyle(.white.opacity(0.3))
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .padding(.vertical, 12)
                .background {
                    Capsule()
                        .fill(.white.opacity(0.20))
                }
        }
    }
}


Ps. If you want it that the menu items are always in ascending order, try applying .menuOrder(.fixed) to the Menu.
